# Woocommerce Product page edit

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, page-template

I am making an online store with every category using a specific page template; that's all done, but now, I want to edit the layout of that page template.

As such, every product will have:

- a name,
- an image,
- a short description;

  *I would like the **product description** to be between the **product name** and **product price tag***,
- a price tag, and
- a *Add to Cart* button.

My challenge: I have no idea about how to get started and need assistance in that regard.

What file do I possibly have to clone and or edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WooCommerce allows you to override its default templates. All templates are located in a `woocommerce/templates` folder. All you have to do is to create a `woocommerce` folder within your theme’s directory, and in this folder duplicate the files you’d like to override.

If you want to update the markup then you will need to copy `archive-product.php` and `content-product.php` files. If you just want to show a little description between the product name and price, then you can simply put following code into your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function show_product_summary(){
    $product_summary = get_the_excerpt();
    echo '<div class="product-summary">'. substr( $product_summary , 0, 30 )  .'</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_product_summary', 10, 2);
```

You will see the product summary like below on product listing page.

[image]

Here is [official blog post](https://www.woothemes.com/2014/08/five-quick-woocommerce-customization-tips/) which will give you quick walkthrough.

Comment: But which php file do I need to duplicate and edit?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for. Thanx!